# Alerts in elastalert are silenced when shouldn't

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert

I want to receive alert for each hit of query. I use rule with "any" type. Documentation says set realert to 0 so I added next lines to config.yaml:

```
realert:
  minutes: 0
```

but I still see in logs

```
INFO:elastalert:Queried rule Client errors from 2016-07-28 21:23 UTC to 2016-07-28 21:38 UTC: 16 / 16 hits
INFO:elastalert:Alert sent to Telegram
INFO:elastalert:Ignoring match for silenced rule Client errors
INFO:elastalert:Ignoring match for silenced rule Client errors
INFO:elastalert:Ignoring match for silenced rule Client errors
....
```

and I receive only first alert. What else could be wrong?

Comment: try adding your 'realert' line to the rule itself, not the config file

Comment: @TallChuck, great, it works! Add an answer to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those lines should be included in the specific rule file, not the config file.